# How to open master detail menu from another content page button click?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to open master details menu from another content page button click event?
so how to do this in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 4):

You can open menu page by setting `MasterDetailPage.IsPresented` to true.

Simple way to do this is `MessagingCenter`. To `MasterDetailPage` add `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` and in your VM add `MessagingCenter.Send`

Example

```
public class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    public MenuPage()
    {
        Title = "Test";
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" }
            }
        };
    }
}

public class DetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public DetailPage()
    {
        var button = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Menu"
        };
        button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                button
            }
        };
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send(EventArgs.Empty, "OpenMenu");
    }
}


public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage();
        masterDetailPage.Master = new MenuPage();
        masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage( new DetailPage());
        MainPage = masterDetailPage;
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<EventArgs>(this, "OpenMenu", args =>
        {
            masterDetailPage.IsPresented = true;
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I added exaple, so you can try

Comment: If this is answer for your question, you should mark it like rigth answer

Answer (score 2):

On the page that you want to open the Drawler Menu, you have to set the "Message Send" on Click Event or whatever you want. In my case, I set this in a image tapped event.

```
public void ToggleDrawer(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  MessagingCenter.Send(EventArgs.Empty, "OpenMenu");
}
```

Now, on the MasterDetailPage (Mainpage.xaml.cs in my case) you have to put a Message Subscribe on that page above InitializeComponent().

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<EventArgs>(this, "OpenMenu", args =>
{
   IsPresented = !IsPresented;
});
```

That works to me.