# How i can get the function or create a button that call the master detail page or menu since a button in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

Im made a custom navigation bar and i want call the menu but since my own menu buttton
the button its in the view home

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Emprender.Views"
                  x:Class="Emprender.Views.MainPage"
                  MasterBehavior="Popover">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MenuPage/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="menu.png"/>
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="menu.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Home />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

You can open menu page by setting `MasterDetailPage.IsPresented` to `true`.

Here is my code in the `views:Home` page. I do not know which place you want to call the menu page. So, I add it in two places.

```
  private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainPage.isMasterPres.IsPresented = true;
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainPage.isMasterPres.IsPresented = true;
        }
```

In the `MainPage`, I set a public static value for `MasterDetailPage` So, we can call it in home view.

```
  public static MasterDetailPage isMasterPres;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            isMasterPres = this;
            MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

            MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Browse, (NavigationPage)Detail);
        }
```

You can use messageCenter to achieve it as well like following thread.

[How to open master detail menu from another content page button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318393/how-to-open-master-detail-menu-from-another-content-page-button-click)

Comment: If the reply is helpful. Please don’t forget to mark this answer(click the ☑️ at the top left corner of this answer ), it will help others who have similar issues.