# Combine hamburger menu an navigation page, Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, hamburger-menu

Is there an easy way to combine the [hamburger menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage) with the [navigation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical) on Xamarion.Forms?

Something this like this:

[image]

How could I do that?

Comment: You can achieve this by using your own custom navigation bar for drawing hamburger menu and navigation at same time, maybe you can take a look [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73692/about-navigation-bar-options)

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Title View` of Xamarin.Forms, to create custom design of navigation bar.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleViewSample"
             x:Class="TitleViewSample.MainPage">
     
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        ...your Layout..
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
 
</ContentPage>
```

Reference Link: https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-title-view-a-powerful-navigation-view

Comment: But it doesn't have any fuctionality at all.

Comment: you can use IsPresented=true; refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318393/how-to-open-master-detail-menu-from-another-content-page-button-click

Comment: you have to manually set the events on image tapped.